# What are the steps for removing dirt from walls?

Tags: painting

Some dirt got on a white wall. I tried to wash it off with a sponge, but it still left some dark streaks or stains.

Should I attempt to scrub it off harder or repaint the wall? Can I repaint only that section or will it not look good?

Answer (score 2):

Just a sponge will likely not do it.  Try some mild detergent in water along with the sponge.  Sometimes the stain will come off and other times it won't.  You have nothing to lose by scrubbing harder at this point since the next step is to repaint the wall or the area that was soiled if it won't come off.

A lot depends on the paint itself.